# Sharing PonyORM's db session across different python module

Tags: python, ponyorm

I initially started a small python project (Python, Tkinter amd PonyORM) and became larger that is why I decided to divide the code (used to be single file only) to several modules (e.g. main, form1, entity, database). Main acting as the main controller, form1 as an example can contain a tkinter Frame which can be used as an interface where the user can input data, entity contains the db.Enttiy mappings and database for the pony.Database instance along with its connection details. I think problem is that during import, I'm getting this error "pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Cannot define entity 'EmpInfo': database mapping has already been generated".  Can you point me to any existing code how should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you import your modules in a wrong order. Any module which contains entity definitions should be imported before `db.generate_mapping()` call.

I think you should call `db.generate_mapping()` right before entering `tk.mainloop()` when all imports are already done.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the problem, the db.generate_mapping() gave me the headache. Placed the db variable and db binding call in a module together with the entities and put the mapping call at the end of the module. Had the hard time looking for the answer because I had the difficulty looking for sample code that separates entity definition from the application logic.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to avoid this is rather than having your `db.generate_mapping()` call happening at a module's top-level code, have a function that a module exports that calls `db.generate_mapping()` after all other modules have been imported.

The pattern I use is to put all of my `db.Entity` subclasses into a single module named `model`, and then at the bottom of `model.py` is:

```
def setup():
    """ Set up the database """
    db.bind(**database_config, create_db=True)
    db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

This function is called by my application's own startup (which is also responsible for setting up `database_config`). This way the correct import and setup order can be guaranteed.

The `db` object itself is also owned by this `model` module; if I need to use it somewhere else I import `model` and use `model.db`.

If you want to further separate things out (with different model classes living in different modules) you can have a module that owns `db`, then your separate model modules, and then a third module that imports `db` and the models and provides the `setup` function. For example, your directory structure could look like this:

- `model/`

  - `__init__.py` -- imports all of the model sub-modules and provides a `setup` function
  - `db.py` -- provides the `db` object itself and any common entities objects that everyone else needs
  - `form1.py`, `form2.py`, etc. -- imports `db` and uses its database object to define the entities

Then your main app can do something like:

```
import model
model.setup()
```